# Laravel 4 only migrations

Tags: php, zend-framework, laravel, laravel-4

I have an application in zend and wanted to add a migrations feature. Was looking at Laravel 4 migrations and they are quite good. Laravel 4 developers are also saying that everything in 4 is modular so I could just use the parts I want. Haven't been able to find any way to do this still, and wanted to know how I could only use the migrations part of Laravel 4 and plug in anywhere else? Or how could pull any one module out of Laravel and plug that in somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4 uses parts of symphony and illuminate for this.

It won't be as simple as dropping in a package and then do 'artisan migrate' but you can install the packages L4 uses for this. The following composer.json file will install what I think is everything you need into a vendor directory.

```
  {
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "4.0.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "illuminate/console": "4.0.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
  }
```

The problem is you'll have to figure out how to use it :-) I personally have no clue at the moment. But you may be able to figure out how to make your own artisan commands for your zend app by looking at L4 source to see how they access the various classes(starting with app/artisan file).

You can check the other dev requirements for illuminate/database here https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database

And you might get some help on the process from this article on artisan commands
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/your-one-stop-guide-to-laravel-commands/

Comment: The Laravel framework isn't really loosely coupled. The application container, will have to be initialized. The config files, and the setup of the objects in the database class also would need to be initialized. I tried tinkering with this and then gave up since it was extremely time consuming. Found it way simpler to include the base laravel app in the zend library folder and then use it only for migrations. I know it's overkill but it worked. :)